# Python: Get Mount Point on Windows or Linux

Tags: python, windows, linux, operating-system, mount

I need a function to determine if a directory is a mount point for a drive.
I found this code already which works well for linux:

```
def getmount(path):
  path = os.path.abspath(path)
  while path != os.path.sep:
    if os.path.ismount(path):
      return path
    path = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(path, os.pardir))
  return path
```

But I'm not sure how I would get this to work on windows. Can I just assume the mount point is the drive letter (e.g. C:)? I believe it is possible to have a network mount on windows so I'd like to be able to detect that mount as well.

Comment: It is possible to have a drive mounted to a path within a drive in windows.  I'd imagine you'd have to look in pywin32 to get a better idea of how to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows didn't use to call them "mount points" [**edit**: it now does, see below!], and the two typical/traditional syntaxes you can find for them are either a drive letter, e.g. `Z:`, or else `\\hostname` (with two leading backslashes: escape carefully or use `r'...'` notation in Python fpr such literal strings).

**edit**: since NTFS 5.0 mount points are supported, but according to [this post](http://brainrack.wordpress.com/2008/05/28/broken-and-ill-documented-api-for-windows-mount-points/) the API for them is in quite a state -- "broken and ill-documented", the post's title says.  Maybe executing the microsoft-supplied [mountvol.exe](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/mountvol.mspx?mfr=true) is the least painful way -- `mountvol drive:path /L` should emit the mounted volume name for the specified path, or just `mountvol` such list all such mounts (I have to say "should" because I can't check right now). You can execute it with `subprocess.Popen` and check its output.

Comment: It *is* possible to have a volume mounted within another drive as well (although I'm not sure if that's the correct terminology).

Answer (score 3):

Do you want to find the mount point or just determine if it is a mountpoint?

Regardless, as commented above, it is possible in WinXP to map a logical drive to a folder.

See here for details:  http://www.modzone.dk/forums/showthread.php?threadid=278

I would try win32api.GetVolumeInformation

```
>>> import win32api
>>> win32api.GetVolumeInformation("C:\\")
    ('LABEL', 1280075370, 255, 459007, 'NTFS')
>>> win32api.GetVolumeInformation("D:\\")
    ('CD LABEL', 2137801086, 110, 524293, 'CDFS')
>>> win32api.GetVolumeInformation("C:\\TEST\\") # same as D:
    ('CD LABEL', 2137801086, 110, 524293, 'CDFS')
>>> win32api.GetVolumeInformation("\\\\servername\\share\\")
    ('LABEL', -994499922, 255, 11, 'NTFS')
>>> win32api.GetVolumeInformation("C:\\WINDOWS\\") # not a mount point
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    pywintypes.error: (144, 'GetVolumeInformation', 'The directory is not a subdirectory of the root directory.')
```

Comment: NB that the win32api is from a package installed separately http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/files/
Thanks for your answer--it also led me to discover how to get the DVD disk tite

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code to return the UNC path pointed to by a drive letter. I suppose there is a more slick way to do this, but I thought I'd contribute my small part.

```
import sys,os,string,re,win32file
for ch in string.uppercase:  # use all uppercase letters, one at a time
    dl = ch + ":"
    try:
        flds = win32file.QueryDosDevice(dl).split("\x00")
    except:
        continue
    if re.search('^\\\\Device\\\\LanmanRedirector\\\\',flds[0]):
        flds2 = flds[0].split(":")
    st = flds2[1]
    n = st.find("\\")
    path = st[n:] 
        print(path)
```