# In Python, how can I get the file system of a given file path

Tags: python, filesystems, filepath

In python, given a directory or file path like /usr/local, I need to get the file system where its available.  In some systems it could be / (root) itself and in some others it could be /usr.

I tried os.statvfs it doesnt help.  Do I have to run the df command with the path name and extract the file system from the output?  Is there a better solution?

Its for linux/unix platforms only.

Thanks

Comment: Do you want just mount path, or some other information?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a slightly modified version of a recipe found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1138383/python-get-mount-point-on-windows-or-linux).
`os.path.realpath` was added so symlinks are handled correctly.

```
import os
def getmount(path):        
    path = os.path.realpath(os.path.abspath(path))
    while path != os.path.sep:
        if os.path.ismount(path):
            return path
        path = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(path, os.pardir))
    return path
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `os.stat` to obtain device number of the file/directory in question (`st_dev` field), and then iterate through system mounts (`/etc/mtab` or `/proc/mounts`), comparing `st_dev` of each mount point with this number.

Answer (score 2):

As `df` itself opens and parses `/etc/mtab`, you could either go this way and parse this file as well (an alternative would be `/proc/mounts`), or you indeed parse the `df` output.